# Constant Solving by ArcGIS Network Analyst?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, network-analyst, network-dataset, service-area

I have created a transportation network dataset from NYC streets.  Upon building and creating the dataset, no significant errors were found in my attributes, connectivity, etc. However, when I run any analysis, whether it be finding drive time service areas or a simple route from point 1 to point 2, I get a constant 'solving...' message and ArcGIS does not respond. I have thoroughly looked through my set up for the dataset and there does not seem to be any obvious errors.

My network dataset is stored within a File .gdb and on a USB drive with ample space.

Does anyone have some troubleshooting ideas or possible solutions?

Comment: Any errors when loading locations?

Comment: No I am able to load locations/facilities or add stops for the route, only when I click 'SOLVE' does this occur, there seem to be no warnings

Comment: How many locations are you loading at a time? Does anything different occur if you only load one location and solve that?

Comment: Yes, I tried to solve the simplest of routes, added two points snapped onto a street segment. Ran Solve, continually says 'Solving' and not responding. I have tried on 2 different systems, so it is not computer speed

Comment: ND stored locally or on a network shared drive?  What kind of travel modes do you have set up on the dataset?  Also, please edit your question in response to comments just to make it easier on other people trying to help (so they don't need to dig through the comments).

Comment: ND is stored on USB drive(no share). I have set up only a driveTime car travel mode.